# A sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral

My friend and I came upon a problem in Real Analysis. It called for a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions $(f_n)$ converging everywhere to a Lebesgue integrable function $f$ such that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \! f_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x < \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \! f(x) \ $$

Unfortunately, we haven't had much luck finding any examples.
Does anyone know of any?

Comment: $f_n=-n\chi_{[0,1/n]}$.

Answer (score 0):

let $f_n(0)=-n$, $f(x)=0, \forall x\in(-\infty,0)\cup[\frac{1}{n},\infty)$, linear between $(0,\frac{1}{n})$, it converges everywhere to $f=-\infty\chi_{\{0\}}$, which has $0$ integral.